# Daily SVN report generation

Tags: svn

Need help in creating some daily reports of a self hosted svn repositry.

I have 6 devs working across projects that is running from a single repository. I need to track which dev wrote how many line of codes daily.  And possibly want to see firsthand what they wrote(a diff).

I looked in svnblame and svnstat both disappointed me big time.

PS: I know it's as easy creating a xml report and coding to get the right data. But i guess it's such a trivial thing and somebody must've worked it out till now.

Comment: Sorry to say but this kind of reports are simply rubbish...But if you like you can take a look to http://statsvn.org/. The number of lines of code is nothing useful...better take a look to things like good readable code, unit- and integration tests (automatically) etc. (Take a look into the book: Clean Code for example..).

Comment: What exactly was the problem with svn blame ? Are you working on windows / linux ? (Using tortoisesvn ? )

Comment: If you're counting lines of code, be aware that Subversion is not really copy-aware.  If a developer moves 30 lines of code as-is from one file to another, you'll probably pick this up as 60 lines changed (30 added and 30 deleted) even though the dev didn't really write anything.  Moving or renaming a file has the same problem.  Some utilities might be able to filter out this sort of thing, but Subversion itself doesn't track it well.  That was one (of many) reasons why our group gave up on "lines of code modified" reports.

Comment: @khmarbaise Agreed that is a rubbish report and as bta mentioned svn is not copy-aware that make things worse. But, i need some method of keeping a progress report. Also, svn blame failed to give me a holistic view i wanted.

Comment: @bta that sucks. Do you prefer any other versioning system ?

Comment: svn blame -r100:100 URL/filename.java prints out exatly what a dev has changed in a particular file (deleted lines or added lines)..what you can't see if a files has been deleted but svn log -r 100 URL will give you this information.

Comment: but for that i need to know what all files a dev changed. I need to know what all files a dev changed, what he changed. In probably a holistic view.

Comment: @gauravtechie: No, I don't have a better system as far as this is concerned.  To really get it right you have to interpret the *meaning* of what changed in each diff, and that's a hard thing to automate.  Honestly, after we gave up trying to implement something like this we discovered that it really didn't give us much useful information in the first place.  "Lines of code written per day" rarely has any sort of correlation to a useful statistic.

Comment: @gauravtechie: We ended up installing Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org), which gave us a nice web-based frontend to SVN and made it much easier to see details of commits and who committed what.  It ended up being far more useful than a "lines of code" report.

Answer (score -1):

[StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) or [SvnStat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnstat/)